# For Loop in Django Template

Tags: python, django, for-loop

I am working on a Django project. It has two Apps, one for explaining the topic, which has its own model, and views, and the second app is a quiz app, which has its own model and view, which will test the ability / learning of the students on each topics.

**The main idea is that for each topic of each book, there will be a quiz to test the ability of the students.**

my book explanation model is as follows:

```
class book_explination(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField  (max_length = 255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length= 250, null = True, blank = True, unique= True)
    lesson_no = models.CharField  (max_length = 255)
    book_text = models.TextField  (blank=False, null=False)
    book_text_explination = models.TextField (blank=False, null=False)
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null= True, blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

my view for the course model is as follows:

```
def maths_topics(request):
    content_list = book_explination.objects.filter(title = "maths")
    return render(request, 'blog/maths_topics.html', {'content_list': content_list})
```

my url on url.py file is as under:

```
path('nahwa_meer_topics/', maths_topics, name = 'maths_topics'),
```

my quiz model is as follows:

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    book_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank = True)
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    number_of_questions = models.IntegerField()
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Quizes'
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

my view for the quiz app is as follows:

```
def maths_quiz(request):
    maths_quiz = Quiz.objects.filter(book__name = "maths")
    return render(request, 'blog/maths_topics.html', {'maths_quiz': maths_quiz})
```

my django HTML template is as under:

```
{% for c in content_list %}
    <ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal">
        {% if c.title == "maths"  %}
            <li> <a href= "{{ c.slug }}" class="list-group-item"> {{ c.title }}</a></li>
            <li> <a href= "{{ c.slug }}" class="list-group-item"> {{ c.lesson_no }}</a></li>
            <li> <a href= "{{ c.slug }}" class="list-group-item"> {{ c.book_text }}</a></li>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
{%endfor%}

{% for c in maths_quiz %}
    <ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal">
        {% if c.name == "maths"  %}
            <li> <a href= "{{ c.slug }}" class="list-group-item"> {{ c.topic }}</a></li>
            <li> <a href= "{{ c.slug }}" class="list-group-item"> {{ c.title }}</a></li>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

the HTML template is reflecting the maths book explanation, however, it is not showing the quiz part of the data.

My aim is to show the topics of a book in an html page, and in front of each topic there should be the quiz, related to that topic, bearing in mind that each topic will have it own separate quiz.

Thanks for your support and help. Looking forward for a positive response from your end.

Regards

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, the `maths_quiz` variable holds a queryset of `Quiz` instances. In your template logic, you display a list item, if an instance's `name` attribute is `"maths"`. However your `Quiz` model has no `name` field at all. Could it be that you meant to check the `book_name` attribute instead?

```html
{% for c in maths_quiz %}
    <ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal">
        {% if c.book_name == "maths"  %}
        ...
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

---

Additionally, I think you made an error in your query to begin with:

```py
...
maths_quiz = Quiz.objects.filter(book__name = "maths")
```

There are two underscores in `book__name`, but your field has only one:

```py
class Quiz(models.Model):
    ...
    book_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

---

Moreover, I just noticed that your whole `if` condition in the template seems to be redundant since you are doing that exact filtering in your query in the view function before passing the results to the template. So there is really no need to check the `book_name` again in the template. **Every** instance in that queryset will have `book_name == "maths"`.

Same goes for the `maths_topics` view.

---

Finally, I assume that either the HTML is actually two separate templates or if not, that you are aware that only one of the two sections will ever be displayed depending on the view that is called, `maths_topics` or `maths_quiz`, not both.

---

As a side note: I would suggest using more descriptive variable names, if possible. Seeing as you are working with multiple `Quiz` instances, I would name the variable something like `maths_quizzes` and for the iteration I would use a name like `quiz` instead of `c`:

```py
def maths_quiz(request):
    maths_quizzes = Quiz.objects.filter(book__name = "maths")
    return render(request, 'blog/maths_topics.html', {'maths_quizzes': maths_quizzes})
```

```html
{% for quiz in maths_quizzes %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

---

#### EDIT

OK, now that you explained a bit more, it seems you *do* think that both querysets should appear somehow. You have **two** separate views. They render separate responses. If you want both querysets passed to your template data, then you should do that in one view:

```py
def maths_view(request):
    content_list = book_explination.objects.filter(title = "maths")
    maths_quiz = Quiz.objects.filter(book_name = "maths")
    return render(
        request, 
        'blog/maths_topics.html', 
        {'content_list': content_list, 'maths_quiz': maths_quiz}
    )
```

Then obviously you need to adjust your URL route to point to that view, something like this (for example):

```py
path('yoururlpath/', maths_view, name = 'maths_view')
```

---

Also, it seems to me that if your two models are so intimately connected, you may want to consider creating some sort of a relationship between them. Namely, if a quiz is *always* related to exactly one book, this seems to call for a foreign key relationship from quiz to book.

I mean something like this:

```py
class Quiz(models.Model):
    book = ForeignKey(to=book_explination, ...)
    ...
```

This would allow you to get all the related objects in the same query.

You can read up on relationships in the Django documentation.

Comment: Daniil thanks for your response. i did the same, but still not reflecting what i wanted to do. My aim is to display, the topic list of a book, and in front of each topic there should be its respective quiz. The topics are coming from one model, and the quiz is coming from another model. I hope now it is now clear.

Comment: @SyedShehabAli I added to my answer. Does that make sense now?

Comment: Thanks for your time. In my book_explination, i already have a foreign key related to quiz. now by clicking on that quiz, it should go to the respective quiz page. how to link that please.

Comment: This is getting out of hand. I think I answered your question sufficiently. I suggest you read up on the basics of Django some more and gather some first-hand experience.